# Unable to get result from get function using React-Moralis

Tags: ethers.js, moralis

I am trying to get the funds of my smart contract. The function is:

```js
function totalBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

I am using moralis and react-moralis for the frontend. I have defined the function to call the `totalBalance`

```js
const { runContractFunction: getFund } = useWeb3Contract({
    abi,
    contractAddress: address,
    functionName: "totalBalance",
    params: {}
});
```

I then async/await it in `useEffect`

```js
const updateUI = async () => {
    const funds = await getFund();
    console.log(funds)
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (isWeb3Enabled) {
        updateUI()
    }
}, [isWeb3Enabled])
```

The problem is that on the first render i get `undefined`, but when i save/change the code in VSCode, it prints out the result.